# How to synchronize send and receive?

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I have a problem in my C# application (async client/server). 
When I execute BeginReceive, and than BeginSend, everything is fine, and the data is proceeded.
But when I execute BeginSend, and than BeginReceive, nothing happens, and BeginSend()/BeginReceive() freezes.

How can I solve this problem? Timeouts doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code? I would guess you have some kind of thread locking going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling EndSend and EndReceive? If not, you should.

> The asynchronous BeginReceive operation must be completed by calling the EndReceive method. Typically, the method is invoked by the callback delegate.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sah14d0.aspx)

Comment: It is called in the callback.